# Multiple Entry Types on GraphQL Fragment

Tags: craft3, graphql

So I am building out a Gatsby Site, which is using Craft in Headless mode as it's content source.
In one Section, I have three entry types. Currently they have identical fields, but may diverge in the future.

I currently have built out my template using one entry type, and have a huge GraphQL query to grab the content.
I am now in the process of moving this query into it's own fragment (and possible sub fragments), to keep a separation of concerns.

The current dilemma I seem to have is that I will end up having to maintain three huge fragments.

I know I can grab the type handle, and pass it through to my template and use it in the query as a variable. But the most logical usage to me doesn't work.

Here was my anticpated usage

In template

```
query getPage($id: [CraftCMS_QueryParameter], $typeHandle: [String]) {
    craftcms {
        entries(id: $id) {
            ...contentPageShape
        }
    }
}
```

In fragment file

```
fragment contentPageShape on CraftCMS_contentPage_$typeHandle_Entry {
    metaDescription
    metaTitle
    id
    title
    slug
    body
    ...loadsMoreFields
}
```

Comment: Hi @david did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue